# How to pause NSURLSessionDownloadTask?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

This is how I use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`:

```
    let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let sessionManager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: sessionConfiguration)

    if let url = NSURL(string: URLString) {

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let sessionDownloadTask = sessionManager.downloadTaskWithRequest(request, progress: nil, destination: { (url, response) -> NSURL in

            self.createDirectoryAtPath(destinationPath)

            return destinationPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

            }, completionHandler: { response, url, error in

                completionBlock(error)
        })

        sessionDownloadTask.resume()
    }
```

I know that I can call `sessionDownloadTask.cancel()` and `sessionDownloadTask.resume()`, but I need to call there `.pause()`, and then `.resume()` to continue download. Is it possible?

Comment: For the AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask: it's not subject of the possibility, it's a fact :(

Answer (score 4):

This method of NSURLSessionTask

```
.suspend()
```

Doc

> A task, while suspended, produces no network traffic and is not subject to timeouts. A download task can continue transferring data at a later time. All other tasks must start over when resumed.

Comment: suspend() method doesn't work for it. Apple documentation says it is not subject to timeouts BUT if you make small experiment it turns out opposite: 1)resume task and suspend it shortly after 2)wait for amount of time equal to timeoutIntervalForRequest (NSURLSessionConfiguration) 3)you will receive timeout error; The only way I see to implement this functionality is to use cancelByProducingResumeData method of download task.

Answer (score 4):

Don't call the `sessionDownloadTask.cancel()` instead use the call `sessionDownloadTask.cancelByProducingResumeData` and whenever you want to resume downloading use the method of `NSURLSession`

`sessionManager.downloadTaskWithResumeData:resumeDataObject`